# Spring amqp listener thread recovery

Tags: java, spring-amqp

I am trying to avoid situation, when thread reading messages from queue is dead, but application is up and running, so its hard to detect problem.

Lets have code:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${enc-correlation.correlation-request-queue}")
public void takeIndexTask(@Payload ConversationList list) throws InterruptedException {
   //just simulation of failure
   throw new OutOfMemoryError(); 
}
```

This will end up with application running, but not processing new messages.

I tried jvm parameter:

```
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
```

which did not stop the application. Is it because it is inside of thread?

So only solution, which is ugly and is working is:

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((thread, t) -> {
        if (t instanceof OutOfMemoryError) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    });
```

Is there a way, how spring amqp would be monitoring listeners threads and in case of "dissapearing" it would start new?

Or at least is there a possibility to stop whole application in case of some exception?

Comment: `>start new` generally speaking, an OOM should be treated as fatal and the JVM should be killed and restarted. The container can't make that decision so you can make it by receiving an event. See my answer.

Comment: Ok, I`ll do it according your suggestion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `ApplicationListener<ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent>` bean or an event listener method...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So55263378Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So55263378Application.class, args);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
    public void listen(String in) {
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    }

    @EventListener
    public void listenForOOMs(ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Consumer thread died with " + event.getThrowable());
    }

}
```

and

```
Consumer thread died with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

Comment: So I will try to go with stopping system in this Listener by calling System.exit(1);