# Heap Space error in SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-integration

We use spring-integration framework extensively. In one of our use case we pull large amount of data from third party api . Doing so it takes some time like 60 sec or more to get a 200 ok response and data . But in some cases the data is so large that we start getting

```
 o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer Stopping container from aborted consumer java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

When this error comes the queue consumer (thread)  dies and is reflected rabbit mq console. I want to figure out a way where I can catch this error log in my application so that a relevant error is raised .

```
@Service
public class FaiureListener implements ApplicationListener<ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent> {
  
    @Autowired
    HangoutAlertPoster alertSender;
    
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent event) {
       alertSender.sendHangoutAlert("[FATAL] Consumer aborted error.  Reason="+event.getReason());
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OOM errors are generally fatal and you have to restart the JVM.

You can add an `ApplicationListener` or `@EventListener` to receive a `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent` which contains the cause.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#consumer-events

If your messages are large, you should reduce the prefetch count so that fewer messages are held in memory, or consider using a `DirectMessageListenerContainer` instead.

See [Choosing a Container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#choose-container).

Comment: Garry I am unable to detect the event  . I followed the example you have written here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263378/spring-amqp-listener-thread-recovery

Comment: You must have done something wrong; double check your work.

Comment: Garry updated the question with code. This code works  on certain errors like Consumer queue(s) not available  . This is not working when there there is out of of memory error

Comment: OOM errors are difficult - as I mentioned they are generally fatal - in some cases, it prevents creating new objects (such as the event). Hence, the proper solution is to avoid thee OOM altogether. As I suggested, you should reduce the `prefetchCount` container property to avoid loading so many large messages into memory. By default, with recent versions, the `prefetchCount` is 250.